# How to use Explain command using Python Mysql connection?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask

Explain Method / Command seems not to be working on python mysql connection. Other queries show correctly results but with explain command nothing is shown. The code prints and comments are int portuguese. I am using DataFrames to display the content of querying result to show the issue / bug / other. Code is indented because it just came out of Visual Studio like that. I Googled it a lot and did not find any clue.

```
            print("#########################################################################################")
            # ANTES DE EXECUTAR CADA UMA DAS QUERYS VEREFICAR QUAIS AS TABELAS QUE SAO UTLIZADAS EM CADA UMA
            # VERIFICAR QUE TABELAS EXISTEM PARA O PROFESSOR
            query = "EXPLAIN " + sqlqueryprof
            print("QUERY EXPLAIN DO PROFESSOR")
            print(query)
            #connection.commit()
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query)
            explain_prof = cur.fetchall()
            print("TABELA EXPLICATIVA DA QUERY DO PROFESSOR")
            data_frame_expl_prof = pandas.DataFrame(list(explain_prof))
            print(data_frame_expl_prof)

            # VERIFICAR QUE TABELAS EXISTEM PARA O ALUNO
            query = "EXPLAIN " + sqlqueryalun
            print("QUERY EXPLAIN DO ALUNO")
            print(query)
            #connection.commit()
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query)
            explain_alun = cur.fetchall()
            print("TABELA EXPLICATIVA DA QUERY DO ALUNO")
            data_frame_expl_alun = pandas.DataFrame(list(explain_alun))
            print(data_frame_expl_alun)

            print("#################################################################")
            # EXECUTAR CADA UMA DAS QUERYS
            cursor_prof = connection.cursor()
            cursor_prof.execute(sqlqueryprof)
            records_prof = cursor_prof.fetchall()

            data_frame_prof = pandas.DataFrame(list(records_prof))
            print("IMPRIMIR O DATA FRAME RESULTANTE DO PROFESSOR A CONEXAO")
            print(data_frame_prof)

            cursor_alun = connection.cursor()
            cursor_alun.execute(sqlqueryalun)
            records_query = cursor_alun.fetchall()

            data_frame_alun = pandas.DataFrame(list(records_query))
            print("IMPRIMIR O DATA FRAME RESULTANTE DO ALUNO A CONEXAO")
            print(data_frame_alun)
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you use `DataFrame` to display the`EXPLAIN` results?

Comment: it could have been any other structure. As long as it was working for other querys at the time i try to make it work with EXPLAIN sql command to show it in terminal... @Lucas

Comment: I've tested on my side and it's working as expected (even with `pandas.DataFrame`). Have you tried printing out the output of your `fetchall`? Are they empty? If so, it's likely that your queries are returning nothing.

Comment: Yes that is the thing @Lucas . Fetchall is returning empty. and as you can see i am just adding "EXPLAIN " to query string. The querys them selfs are returning something. When i put the explain -> Empty results...

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you used `cur.fetchall()` instead of `cursor.fetchall()`?

```
[...]
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
explain_prof = cursor.fetchall()
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks @Lucas really but nop. `cur = mysql.connection.cursor()`         `connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='jg_teste',
                                         user='root',
                                         password='xxxx')                         cursor = connection.cursor()`                                             diferent things actually i am using two data bases... but no confusion no... thanks

Comment: Would be worth a try though ;)

Comment: full code here: [GitHub](https://github.com/joaogracio/SqlParser/blob/master/app_api.py) @Lucas as i told you `cur` and `cursor` are diferent things...

Comment: Sure, they are 2 different things, and that's the thing! You can't use either of one whenever you like. In your case, you execute `cursor.execute(query)`, so you **MUST** call `cursor.fetchall()` to get the results, not `cur.fetchall()`.

Comment: The way you said it... i just starting to wondering if **explain**  command was not allowed trought python connector